# Insert text into Table in a word processing document (Open XML )

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ms-word, openxml

I have Document file with header and footer part. In the footer portion I have one table.

So now I am trying insert text into Table cell. But whenever I try to do by this code it will be append paragraph type and change the height and weight of the table .

```
  using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ORiFilepath, true))
        {
         var docPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
            if (docPart.FooterParts.Count() > 0)
            {
                //List<Table> table = docPart.FooterParts..Elements<Table>().ToList();
                foreach (FooterPart footer in docPart.FooterParts)
                {
                    List<Table> table = footer.Footer.Elements<Table>().ToList();
                    if (table.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var footertable = table[0];
                        TableRow row1 = footertable.Elements<TableRow>().ElementAt(1);
                        string text1 = cell1.InnerText;
                        if (text1 == "")
                        {
                            cell1.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("TEXT"))));
                           
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

can I insert text into the cell Using

```
cell1.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("TEXT"))));,
```

or What should be the method ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use to add text to a cell. Hopefully it's useful.

The `CreateCellProperties`  and `CreateParagraph` methods just encapsulate the corresponding objects in OpenXML SDK (`TableCellProperties` and `ParagraphProperties`) which you don't really need to write text.

Let me know if you still have problems:

```
         public TableCell CreateCell(Shading shading, int width, int gridSpan, 
            TableCellBorders borders, TableVerticalAlignmentValues valign,
            JustificationValues justification, Color color, string text, 
            VericalMergeOptions mergeOptions)

        {
            // Set up Table Cell and format it.
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            

            TableCellProperties cellProperties = CreateCellProperties(shading, width, gridSpan, borders, valign, mergeOptions);
            ParagraphProperties props = CreateParagraphProperties(justification, color);
            
            // Set cell and paragraph
            Run run = CreateRun(color, text);
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(new List<OpenXmlElement>
            {
                props,
                run
            });

            // Append the run and the properties
            cell.Append(new List<OpenXmlElement>
            {
                cellProperties,
                paragraph
            });
            return cell;
        }

        protected Run CreateRun(Color color, string text = "")
        {

            Run run = new Run(new List<OpenXmlElement>{
                new RunProperties(color.CloneNode(true)),
            });

            if (text != "") run.Append(new Text(text));

            return run;
        }
```